# access sharepoint documents from J2EE system

Tags: jakarta-ee, sharepoint-2010, cmis

I have a J2EE online system and I am integrating office365 and sharepoint online to this system.

My Goal: access documents that are inside the sharepoint document library through my J2EE system.

What I only have now:
- My J2EE system
- Office 365 account (that includes "Sharepoint Online")

What are the steps needed  in order to reach my goal ? (for example: installing sharepint server, downloading sharepoint administrator toolkit, how to use contect management interoperability services CMIS, is there any sharepoint development needed...etc )

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is all what you need. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg454740.aspx

Comment: Dear Luis,
Thanks a lot for your reply.
But may you please tell me what do i need? I am not familiar with webservices.. Do i need to implement something in .NET, or the J2EE can call directly the sharepoint webservice ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first step you need the integration of you application with sharepoint you might need this : [Reading a SharePoint list with Java](https://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/reading-a-sharepoint-list-with-java-tutorial/)
you can access documents that are inside the sharepoint document library through your J2EE system. You must read the documentation carefully before starting on it here is the link will be help full to you [how to get file content from sharepoint list using restapi in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422868/how-to-get-file-content-from-sharepoint-list-using-restapi-in-java)