# how to get file content from sharepoint list using restapi in java

Tags: java, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to get the content of a file from sharepoint list using java through rest api

Can anyone help me,I am a newbie to sharepoint

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Sharepoint provides a REST API to access lists. 
Here is a sample end point to start with.

```
http://server/site/_api/lists/getbytitle('listname')
```

Here is more documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest

Edit:
To download file use the following URL:

```
http://server/site/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Test/Shared Documents/" + sourcefile.get_name() + "')/$value?@target='myhosturl'
```

Refer to 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/02bfbcdc-73c8-4fa5-8967-cfd903a0d72e/javascript-client-object-model-openbinary-method

http://www.techmikael.com/2013/07/how-to-copy-files-between-sites-using.html for more information.

Comment: thanks uday for your answer,but with the above link i am able to get the xml data(metadata) for the files in the lists,but I want the complete file content to store the files in my local system,how can i do it.

Is there any way to get the url of a file in list using the api,so that when i hit that url i can download the file to my local system.

Comment: Updated the answer.